# Qt5 emit a signal on behalf of another object

Tags: qt5, signals-slots

Is it possible to `emit` a `signal` on behalf of another `QObject`? the reason I would like to do this is that it would be very useful when writing mock/test code and simply want to simulate that a certain object emitted a signal.

I tried to use

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(otherObject, "mySignal", Q_ARG(QString, myArg));
```

because the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) says:

> [...] Invokes the member (a **signal** or a slot name) on the object obj.[...]

But this does not work for me. The signal is simply not emitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply invoke the signal through the class like so:

```
otherObject.mySignal("Testing!");
```

## Edit

Good point on the thread-safety issue.  I got it to work as well with the invokeMethod solution by explicitly setting the connection type.  If your objects are in different threads, you'd need to use the QueuedConnection rather than the DirectConnection.  Here is my simple test case:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QObject>
#include "Stub.h"

int main()
{
    Stub stub;
    Stub2 stub2;

    QObject::connect(&stub, &Stub::TestSignal, &stub2, &Stub2::TestReceiver);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&stub, 
                              "TestSignal", 
                              Qt::DirectConnection, 
                              Q_ARG(QString, "myArg"));

    return 0;
}
```

**Stub.h**

```
#ifndef STUB_H
#define STUB_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Stub : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void TestSignal(QString s);
};

class Stub2 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void TestReceiver(QString s) {qDebug() << "Got s:" << s;}
};

#endif // STUB_H
```

Comment: Well the whole point is that I don't know how many other objects subscribe to the original signal. So instead of keeping track of all this I would instead just simulate an emit and let everything run its course as usual.

Comment: Will this not accomplish your goal? Based on your invokeMethod example, it looks to me like you have a reference to the object that needs to emit the signal. My solution just tells the referenced object to emit the signal.

Comment: If this is so, what about thread safety? For example in the case where my object is running in an event loop on another thread? In that case one would expect invokeMethod to work, which it did not (for me atleast).

Comment: Wow! You really stepped up to the challenge! This is what S.O. is made of; awesome answers. Thanks alot. +1 and accepted.

Comment: By the way, you state that one should select QueuedConnection in your answer, but in the example code you still have DirectConnection. Also in Stub2 you didnt specify TestReceiver to be a slot.

Comment: You're welcome! The DirectConnection is actually correct for my test case since the classes live in the same thread. QueuedConnection only applies if the classes are in separate threads. As of Qt5, they introduced the connect syntax that I used, which can connect to any function, slot or otherwise. You are correct that it would need a slot declaration if you are using the legacy connect syntax.

Comment: Yeah, `emit` is just a hint to MOC, which evaluates to nothing. So, since signals are (always) public methods - you can call them directly